# Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper 8 Intellisense Slow

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, intellisense

Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, and ReSharper 8.2.3 causes super laggy and slow IntelliSense responsiveness.  Also, often times the dropdown is cut off and not rendered entirely, and sometimes the entire Visual Studio window turns black and becomes unresponsive for many seconds.

My system is running an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Video Card with 32 GB of RAM and an Intel Core i7-7820HK @ 2.90-4.40 GHz

See the animated gif below for an example.

[image: odd intellisense rendering]

Anyone have similar issues and a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SSD? Secondly, try the instructions given here - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html. I had the same issue that you mentioned and it was fixed by following instructions given under section - "Configuring Visual Studio preferences" in the above link. Also have a look at this update by JetBrains - >https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546919-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow